# Unpack Failed Error while Setting up Git Repository in Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: git, svn, github, tfs

I am trying to migrate from svn to TFS git. I setup a new git repository in my local disk and I have all the history from svn. Now I want to push the code to centralized Repo in TFS. I created a new Repo in TFS and I tried the following

```
   git remote add origin  http://remoteserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepo

   git push -u origin --all
```

The output is as below:

```
  $ git push -u origin --all
  Counting objects: 1801, done.
  Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
  Compressing objects: 100% (1743/1743), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (1801/1801), 5.72 MiB | 1.28 MiB/s, done.
  Total 1801 (delta 830), reused 0 (delta 0)
  remote: Analyzing objects... (1801/1801) (4585 ms)
  error: unpack failed: error File upload already completed.
  remote: Storing packfile...
  To http://remoteserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepo
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (File upload already completed.)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'http://remoteserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepo'
```

I am not sure what the error is and couldn't find any help online. I am using 32-bit Git 2.10.0 on Windows.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side with `git push origin master`. You may try to create a light local Git Repository and test whether you can reproduce this issue.
2. You may try pushing with `--no-thin` argument to see whether it works.

Comment: The problem was that I was missing the required permissions on the Team Foundation Server. I was able to push one file at a time but not the entire repo at once.

I was misguided by the totally unrelated error message. Thank you for helping.